# Why does using a tun interface from multiple processes cause it to stutter?

Tags: c, linux, epoll, tun

I have written a working user-space tunnel protocol, which opens tun0.

```
void peer_tun_open(struct peer *peer) {
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int err;

    proc_assert_master();

    if ((peer->tun_fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR)) == -1) {
        LOG_ERROR_1("%s", "open /dev/net/tun");
        exit(1);
    }
    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TUN | IFF_NO_PI;

    if ((err = ioctl(peer->tun_fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *) &ifr)) == -1) {
        LOG_ERROR_1("%s", "ioctl TUNSETIFF");
        close(peer->tun_fd);
        exit(1);
    }
    ...
```

So long as I use tun0 from only one process' epoll, everything works fine.

(I am able to use UDP sockets from multiple processes, without problems, with SO_REUSEPORT, etc.  UDP ports are opened by the children, but the tun file descriptor is inherited via `fork()`.)

When I add the tun0 fd to multiple process' epolls, random delays of 100-3000ms affect all packets arriving on tun0.

```
static void proc_epoll_callback(const char *key, void *ob, size_t index, void *extra) {
    struct peer *peer = (struct peer *)ob;
    int epoll_fd = *(int *) extra;
    struct epoll_event event = {0};

    if (peer->worker_id != state.proc_worker_id) return; // only one process must listen to a each tun interface, otherwise 100-3000ms delays occur

    event.events = EPOLLIN;
    event.data.fd = peer->tun_fd;

    if (epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, event.data.fd, &event)) {
        LOG_ERROR_1("failed to add fd: %d to epoll fd: %d for peer %s", event.data.fd, epoll_fd, peer->name);
    } else {
        LOG_DEBUG_1("added fd: %d to epoll fd: %d for peer %s", event.data.fd, epoll_fd, peer->name);
    }
}
```

What causes these delays?

How can I use tun0 from multiple worker processes, without these delays?

Comment: You should use multiqueue tuntap interface for paralleling (See https://docs.kernel.org/networking/tuntap.html)